# How to insert bulk records in nifi

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert, apache-nifi

am new to nifi am trying to do bulk insert in mysql using nifi below is my sample flow structure.

```
FetchFile -> 
ConvertRecord (covert csv to json) -> 
SplitJson -> 
EvaluateJsonPath -> 
routeOnAttribute -> 
JoltTransformJson (adding new key value pair) -> 
MergeContent (merge all flowfiles) -> 
ConvertJsontoSql (converting json to sql) -> 
ExecuteSql
```

here executeSql insert only one record instead of all the records

mergeContent contains the following JSON structure

```
{"batch_id":"123","name":"xyz","age":"26"},
{"batch_id":"123","name":"abc","age":"29"},
{"batch_id":"123","name":"fff","age":"30"}
```

but executeSql inserts only the first json others are all not inserted. please somebody help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess, you just need to add [ and ] brackets as header and footer in merge content. Then you'll have a correct json array of objects...

Comment: Where does the comma at the end of the JSON object come from? I can't see how any of those processors would write one JSON per line with a comma at the end, unless the array brackets were also written

Comment: @daggett Thanks for the response after adding [ and ] brackets as header and footer it works, but it inserts record one by one is there any way to insert in bulk?? inserting record one by one takes long time since am inserting huge number of records.

Comment: @mattyb am separating the JSON object with comma in  MergeContent processor

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change record reader ?

Using JsonPathReader you can add one record but If you use JsonTreeReader you can insert as bulk.